# signal.spectrogram find maximum frequency for given segment

Tags: python, scipy, signal-processing, fft, spectrogram

After calling [scipy.signal.spectrogram](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.spectrogram.html) is it possible to determine the strengths of different frequencies for a given segment?

i.e. after executing the following:

```
fs, data = wavfile.read(waveFile)    

sampleFreqs, segmentTimes, sxx= signal.spectrogram(data, fs, nperseg=256, noverlap=128, nfft=512, window=('hamming'))

fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(1, 2, figsize=(12,4))    
ax1.pcolormesh((len(segmentTimes)*segmentTimes/segmentTimes[-1]), sampleFreqs, 10*np.log10(sxx))
ax1.set_title('Spectrogram');
ax1.set_xlabel('Segment')
ax1.set_ylabel('Frequency')
```

which produces a spectrogram such as [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FAIMq.png).

Can I find out from `sxx` what the strongest frequency is for the 10th segment, for example?

Cheers,
David

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look at [numpy.argmax](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.argmax.html). Your data look clean enough, so that should work, no filtering required.

Comment: Thanks. I was expecting the shape of sxx to be (segmentTimes, sampleFreqs) to match the spectrogram, but in fact the shape was (sampleFreqs, segmentTimes). Now I realise this I can determine the values as I expected.